# date. hwclock keep showing wrongly everytime after reboot

Tags: centos, time-zone

Edited question to better reflect situation.  (My hwclock and date is not showing correctly)

I am on +GMT 8 and i have set my hwclock to localtimezone by doing the following

```
rm /etc/adjtime
system-config-date -- to set the correct date/time
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore localtime
hwclock --systohc --localtime
```

Please check my configurations

```
[root@sjoam2 etc]# date
Sun Aug  2 03:24:59 SGT 2015

[root@sjoam2 etc]# hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1438457074 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1438457074 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on local time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in local time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/08/02 03:25:16
Hw clock time : 2015/08/02 03:25:16 = 1438457116 seconds since 1969
Sun 02 Aug 2015 03:25:16 AM SGT  -0.672466 seconds


[root@sjoam2 etc]# cat /etc/adjtime 
0.000000 1438457074 0.000000
1438457074
LOCAL
```

All seems good. The date and hwclock are showing correct timing until I done a reboot. After the reboot, the date is added another +8 hours even though i have already specified the hwclock is in localtime.

```
[root@sjoam2 ~]# date
Sun Aug  2 11:30:06 SGT 2015 **-- why +8 hours ? i have specified hwclock in localtime**

[root@sjoam2 ~]# hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1438457074 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1438457074 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on local time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in local time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/08/02 03:30:09
**Hw clock time : 2015/08/02 03:30:09 = 1438457409 seconds since 1969
Sun 02 Aug 2015 03:30:09 AM SGT  -0.626865 seconds  -- still showing the correct timing for hwclock**
```

Can some gurus shed some light on this ?

Regards,
Noob

Comment: what is the OS you are using?

Comment: @Sachith centos6.6

Comment: what is the time zone you live?

Comment: SGT is singapore time

Comment: can u paste the /etc/sysconfig/clock file output

Comment: [root@sjoam2 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
# The time zone of the system is defined by the contents of /etc/localtime.
# This file is only for evaluation by system-config-date, do not rely on its
# contents elsewhere.
ZONE="Asia/Singapore"

Answer (score 0):

First make a backup of local time file.

```
sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
```

then,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Country/City /etc/localtime
```

replace your country and city where you live. save and reboot.
for more informations follow these two threads. [change timezone](https://chrisjean.com/change-timezone-in-centos/) , i think [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214336/why-is-the-localtime-reset-to-the-default-timezone?newreg=cb7f43c38676444fa7b47a00a912bf57) has some additional details for you.

Comment: Already done before my original post.  There is a symbolic link /etc/localtime pointing to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Country/City Asia/Singapore already

Comment: What about your PC battery?

Comment: how do i check my pc battery ? - i am actually on vmware though

Comment: @Noob, if the battery in the system was dead, the clock would be off by years not hours. I.e., if you powered it off and on it would go back to a default date some time in the past not today's date, but 8 hours ahead.

Comment: yes, he didn't mention about a VM.

Answer (score 0):

If Singapore time is [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)/[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time plus 8 hours and you are put 16 hours ahead when you reboot, your system appears to be compensating twice for the offset.

On a CentOS 7 system, [I had a problem with the time being off by several hours](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2014/12/30#set_time_zone) until I used the timedatectl command. E.g.:

`timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Singapore`

The "set-timezone" option does the following:

```
set-timezone [TIMEZONE]
           Set the system time zone to the specified value. Available
           timezones can be listed with list-timezones. If the RTC is
           configured to be in the local time, this will also update the RTC
           time. This call will alter the /etc/localtime symlink. See
           localtime(5) for more information.
```

Though the hardware clock on that system is using UTC time. E.g., I see the following:

```
# hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.23.2
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 0 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 0 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on UTC time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/08/01 20:54:34
Hw clock time : 2015/08/01 20:54:34 = 1438462474 seconds since 1969
Sat 01 Aug 2015 04:54:34 PM EDT  -0.904866 seconds
```

The last line from the `hwclock --debug` command above shows the correct local time for that system in the relevant time zone.

On that system, I see the following for /etc/localtime:

`# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 38 Oct  5  2014 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`

If you enter `ls -l /etc/localtime` do your still see it pointing to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore`

Comment: Maybe the hardware clock is affected by bios.

Comment: @redbeam, that's a good suggestion to check the time setting there as well.

Comment: @moonpoint my /etc/localtime is pointing to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore and my bios time is the same as the hwclock --debug output, which is set as localtime. the hwclock and bios is reflecting correct time. but date is adding additional 8 hours to the already correct time.  i am on centos 6.6, thus i dont have timedatectl or set time-zone command. but with command system-config-date i have already set the correct country and timezone, please advise what could be wrong ?

Comment: @Noob, it isn't apparent to me based on the information you provided why your time is still 8 hours off. It seems to me, also, that you have the settings right. There is a sister site to this one [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) where someone may be able to provide a fix for the problem if you post your question there with the details you provided here.